# Unobstrusive data format in web applications

Tags: html, web-applications

When working with HTML5, JavaScript, PHP and MySQL, is there a way to display input data in a different format, without altering the actual value?

For example if we have

```
<input value='10000.5'>
```

the actual value is what we see looking directly into the html code, but in the website interface we want to show 10.000,5... like some kind of CSS for data.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
<input value='10000.5' placeholder='10.000,5' />
```

Comment: No, i refer about displaying the actual value of the input in a different format without altering it. But thanks, I edited my question so it is more clear now.